# Extract \ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude44 emoji string from a a given string:

Tags: php, regex, unicode, utf-16

I have a string like:-

```
Hi, Jax\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude44! can we go for a coffee?
```

Now, the emoji are in UTF16(I think). I need to extract the '`\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude44`' and give a space between each pair, something like this.

```
Hi, Jax\ud83d\ude1b \ud83d\ude44! can we go for a coffee?
```

**How can I achieve this in PHP?**

More Examples as I would need:-

```
Hi, Jax\ud83d\ude1b \ud83d\ude44! can we go for\ud83d\ude1b \ud83d\ude44 a coffee?
```

So What needed to be done:-

1. User may or may not leave any space after any normal word and just type a emoji. I mean, `Jax\ud83d\ude1b` and `Jax \ud83d\ude1b`.
2. The emoji may always vary, since they are coming from DB. How to split each emoji pattern into pairs?

Comment: A naive approach: `str_replace("\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude44", "\ud83d\ude1b \ud83d\ude44", $s)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, It also needs to extract eacch emoji presence in the String. The string is generating dynamic. So the emoji pattern, string pattern may vary.

Comment: Is `Jax\` a part of the emoji string?

Comment: @protld. No, Jax is a normal word(a name). But the total string is saved with emoji just starting after 'Jax'. No space is present.

Comment: You could extract with `((?:\\u[\da-fA-F]{4}){2})`. [See regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mR2nL7/1)

Comment: @ClasG Can you provide me a sample example? I would be grateful.

Comment: @ClasG I need a PHP example to extract all the emoji pattern and replace them with pattern of a space between the pair!

Comment: Are you sure all emoji are in 4 bytes like in sample?

Comment: Yes, mostly the emoticons are 4bytes @revo

Comment: And are Unicode escape sequences there as being a literal text?

Comment: That's how they have been saved in the DB. Literally. @revo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure what you want, but this shows how to *(1) and (2)*.

```
$input = 'Hi, Jax\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude44! can we go for a coffee?';

$pattern = '/((?:\\\\u[\dA-F]{4}){2})/i';
preg_match_all ( $pattern , $input , $mtchs); 
print_r($mtchs);
```

I don't really *speak* php, but the `preg_match_all` extract all emojis to an array - `$mtchs` (1).

Then for (2) the `preg_replace` inserts a space between them if there are back to back emojis (or rather *two unicode letters followed by the beginning of another - `\u`).

```
$pattern = '/((?:\\\\u[\dA-F]{4}){2})(\\\\u)/i';
print_r(preg_replace($pattern, '$1 $2', $input));
```